How to expand $(D_\mu\Phi)^\dagger(D^\mu\Phi)$ in $SU(2)$
I would like to calculate the following expression:
$(D_\mu\Phi)^\dagger(D^\mu\Phi)$ where $D_\mu\Phi = (\partial_\mu-\frac{ig}{2}\tau^aA_\mu^a)\Phi$ and $A_\mu^a$ are the components of a real $SU(2)$ gauge Field and $\Phi$ is a complex two component spinor.
Unfortunately I have not yet come to a result.
Here is what I have tried:
$(\tau^a)^\dagger = \tau \\$
Inserting the definition of $D_\mu$ yields
Inserting the definition of $D_\mu$ yields
$\partial_\mu\Phi^\dagger \partial^\mu \Phi - \partial^\mu(\Phi^\dagger)\frac{ig}{2}\tau^a A_\mu^a\Phi+\frac{ig}{2} \Phi^\dagger \tau^aA^{a}_{\mu}\partial^\mu \Phi+\frac{g^2}{4}\Phi^\dagger\tau^aA^a_\mu \tau^bA^{b\mu}\Phi.$
can i simplify this expression even further?
